# bash in systemctl . error 2 launch at start

Tags: bash, systemctl

lHello, in preparation for using a RP4 (running ubuntu server) , i am trying to have a bash script that is kicked off on boot... and relaunches is killed. i have included the steps belle along with the content of the file. Any clue on the error code or why it is not work would be greatly appreciated.

any idea on the exit code with a status of 2?

thank you.

```
uburntu@ubuntu:/etc/systemd/system$ cat prysmbeacon_altona.service 
[Unit]
Description=PrysmBeacon--Altona
Wants=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
DynamicUser=yes
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/Desktop/prysm/prysm.sh beacon-chain --altona --datadir=/home/ubuntu/.eth2
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/Desktop/prysm
Restart=always
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/systemd/system$ systemctl daemon-reload
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.reload-daemon ===
Authentication is required to reload the systemd state.
Authenticating as: Ubuntu (ubuntu)
Password: 
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/systemd/system$ systemctl start prysmbeacon_altona
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to start 'prysmbeacon_altona.service'.
Authenticating as: Ubuntu (ubuntu)
Password: 
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/systemd/system$ systemctl status prysmbeacon_altona.service
● prysmbeacon_altona.service - PrysmBeacon--Altona
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/prysmbeacon_altona.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-07-23 15:51:48 CEST; 111ms ago
    Process: 3407 ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/Desktop/prysm/prysm.sh beacon-chain --altona --datadir=/home/ubuntu/.eth2 (code=exited, status=2)
   Main PID: 3407 (code=exited, status=2)
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/systemd/system$
```

Comment: Did you try this command using sudo?

Comment: Please put the content of the bash script you are trying to run it. Make sure to remove any secrets(if any).

Comment: I have not tried with sudo... when I am logged in as ubuntu (username)..and open a terminal.. it runs without the sudo.. so  would suspect that we dont need it..   as for the source of the script.. it can be found at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prysmaticlabs/prysm/master/prysm.sh